# Stop background color of one div covering the content of another, rotated and thus overlapping, div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT: jsFiddle with the exact problem. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ggxmcypd/)

I would like the rotated text in the header to not be cut off as it is shown [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/berWe.png)

So I have a table which headers are rotated like below.

[image: table with rotated headers]

Now I'm trying to make the header of the table stick so that when I scroll the header stays in place. I have used [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer.html) jquery plugin to do this.

The problem is that in order to display the table correctly when scrolled the header needs to have a background color of white or else it will look like this.

[image: table scrolled]

But if I set the background color of the `<th>`'s as white then this color overlaps the text of the other headers overlapping. Like below where I've set the background color of the 4th row as white.

[image]

Is there some way I can make the background color of the th not overlap the text in other th's rotated over that th? I've tried setting the z-index of the text really high but it has had no effect.

HTML:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Fault Finding and Testing</th>
        <th>Replacing Faulty lightbulbs</th>
        <th>Switching MCSBS MCCBs</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div>Bob Bobbers</div></td>
        <td><div></div></td>
        <td><div></div></td>
        <td><div></div></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

CSS:

```
th.rotate {
height: 110px;
white-space: nowrap;

 }
th.rotate > div {
     transform: 
     /* Magic Numbers */
     translate(25px, 37px)
     /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
     rotate(325deg);
     width: 30px;
     padding: 5px;
 }
 th> div > span {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
     padding: 5px 5px;
 }
```

Javascript:

```
$(".taskApproverTable").tableHeadFixer({'left' : 1, 'head': true});
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show your code so we have a way of replicating the problem?

Comment: Added mock up code, actual code is very complex.

Comment: `thead > tr{background:white;}` try this

Comment: The tr actually scrolls it's only the actual th's that stay still, so this will not work.

Comment: @OneTwo isn't it better to fix the thead instead of th.

Comment: Probably, but the plugin I am using fixes the th.

Comment: I've set up a quick fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ggxmcypd/ I did have to add a bit to your css to get it functioning, but I'm not seeing the problem described above. Perhaps the parts you left are the cause. You could update this fiddle with all of your code example and append it to your question to make life a bit easier for us to answer.

Comment: This fiddle does have the same problem for me. This is what I'm seeing http://i.imgur.com/b14cyho.png The text cut off in the header by the background color of the other header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set different z-index on each th so the most left one will have highest z-index:

```js
/**
* setRotatedTableHeadersToNotHideEachOther sets z-index on given 
* table th's so all th text will be visible when rotated.
* The left most th will have the highest z-index and the last th will have z-index 0; 
* @param tableSelector is a jQuery selector for the table that will have its th z-index changed
* @example 
*           fix all tables that has class taskApproverTable
*           setRotatedTableHeadersToNotHideEachOther(".taskApproverTable");
*/
function setRotatedTableHeadersToNotHideEachOther(tableSelector){
  var tables = $(tableSelector);
  for(var i=0,nrTables = tables.length;i<nrTables;i++){
  var table = tables[i];
      var ths = $('th',table);
      for(var j=0, nrThs = ths.length;j<nrThs;j++){
          // get th from right to left
          var th = ths[nrThs - j - 1];
          // set lowest z-index on the one to the right
          $(th).css('z-index', j);
    }
  }
}

setRotatedTableHeadersToNotHideEachOther(".taskApproverTable");
```

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggxmcypd/2/)